# Dense and algebraically independent subset of $\mathbb{R}$ in $(\mathbb{R}, <, +, ·, 0, 1)$.

Tags: real-numbers, model-theory

I was trying to construct a dense subset $D$ of $\mathbb{R}$ that was also algebraically independent, that is, for any $x\in D$ $(x\notin acl(D\cup\{0,1\}\setminus \{x\}))$. I know they exist in saturated extensions of $(\mathbb{R}, <, +, ·, 0, 1)$. However, the usual examples of dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that come to my mind are not algebraically independent. Is there any known example of such a set with an easy description?

Comment: You don't need "saturated extension" whatever that is.  Zorn's lemma is enough.  "An example with a description" would be interesting, however.

Comment: @GEdgar a saturated extension of a first-order structure $M$ is an elementary superstructure $N\succeq M$ such that, for any subset $A\subset N$ with $|A|<|N|$, every type over $A$ (read: every consistent collection of first-order formulas with parameters from $A$) is realized in $N$. as you note, this is overkill in this case, but it can be useful for these kinds of things in more general contexts. (+1 on your answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The seqeuence $\sqrt{p_k}$ (squareroots of the primes) is linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$.  By the [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), the sequence
$\exp(\sqrt{p_k})$ is algebraically independent over $\mathbb Q$.  We may choose nonzero rationals $r_k$ so that $r_k\exp(\sqrt{p_k})$ is dense in $\mathbb R$; this sequence is still algebraically independent.